# Is Volley API suitable for getting an apps initial configuration data?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have successfully implemented Volley for network request processing. However, when my app starts up it goes out and gets a configuration file which it needs.  I am wondering if Volley is the right choice for getting this very early initial configuration data?  Does it take some time to instantiate the volley threads for queue, cache etc, and so perhaps for this one initial request it is the wrong choice?  I wanted to get some feedback on this. On the one hand its a good choice because of its RetryPolicy settings that will attempt several times to full-fill the request, on the other-hand it could it take some time to get the volley request queue setup, and volley threads running? Am I better off issuing this initial request using just an AsyncTask?

Comment: Volley still very new, i would AsyncTask head first for sure.

Comment: @TestBest you asked 9 out of the latest 11 questions with the Volley tag yet almost did not accept any answers. Community members are trying to help each other, so if someone helped you fix your problem it is customary to accept their answer or at least comment and say what was wrong with it. It also helps others who have the same question or a similar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Volley if you find its features useful or want to maintain consistency with the way you perform network requests in the rest of your app.

The amount of time required for your Volley setup to run is not an important. The round trip time needed to fetch your configuration file will be in the 100s of ms. Whereas setting up Volley will require 10s of ms at most.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `first` request, i would preffer to use `AsyncTask`, Volley is really very good but this is a an important process at the very beggining of the app, maybe at that time Volley is not `ready` yet or will take `some additional meaningful time` to do the request, so `AsyncTask` it's better for this particular case, plus you will have all in all control on how this `first` request would be done.

EDIT: i just saw Ficus Kirkpatrick (the Volley library master mind), and he said that you could create a `RequestQueue` on demand or create at first and keep it like a Singleton for the rest of code, so hearing this, you should try it with AsyncTask and Volley and check what are the results in term of performance, i still think a simpler AsyncTask will do the job better than instanlly using Volley, he also said that of course Volley is not a must, so i guess this is one of the case where is not a must.

Comment: well if I can confirm that it does take much time to setup, one of Volley's advantages for getting the initial config is its retry policy.  If its really important to get the config than the retry policy would be a best effort to get the config, but still not sure if there are any risks in waiting for volley to initialize in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an `AsyncTask` infrastructure, but like the ease of creating a `Volley` request, consider using [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidQuery), which follows the same pattern as a `Javascript` request. For example, to get `JSON` from `example.com`, you can use the shorthand method:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.example.com", null, new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) params[0];
        //TODO handle json
    }
});
```

or the longhand method:

```
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url("http://www.example.com")
                        .type("GET")
                        .dataType("json")
                        .success(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) params[0];
                                //TODO handle json
                            }
                         })
                         .error(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                AjaxError e = (AjaxError) params[0];
                                Log.e("$", "Error " + e.status + ": " + e.error);
                            }
                         }));
```